# insert value in a matrix in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, concatenation

I wrote this matlab code in order to concatenate the results of the integration of all the columns of a matrix extracted form a multi matrix array.

"datimf" is a matrix composed by 100 matrices, each of 224*640, vertically concatenated.
In the first loop i select every single matrix.
In the second loop i integrate every single column of the selected matrix
obtaining a row of 640 elements. 
The third loop must concatenate vertically all the lines previously calculated.

Anyway i got always a problem with the third loop. Where is the error?

```
singleframe = zeros(224,640); 
int_frame_all = zeros(1,640); 
conc = zeros(100,640); 

for i=0:224:(22400-224)  
   for j = 1:640         
      for k = 1:100      
         singleframe(:,:) = datimf([i+1:(i+223)+1],:);
         int_frame_all(:,j) = trapz(singleframe(:,j));
         conc(:,k) = vertcat(int_frame_all);
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate vertically"?  .`vertcat` is not doing anything in your code above.  I suspect one of your loops is not necessary as the outer and inner loops are the same length (100 iterations).

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to do this without using any *explicit* loops (edited in response to rayryeng's comment below. It's also worth noting that using `cellfun` may not be more efficient than explicitly looping.):

```
nmats = 100;
nrows = 224;
ncols = 640;

datimf = rand(nmats*nrows, ncols);

% convert to an nmats x 1 cell array containing each matrix
cellOfMats = mat2cell(datimf, ones(1, nmats)*nrows, ncols);

% Apply trapz to the contents of each cell
cellOfIntegrals = cellfun(@trapz, cellOfMats, 'UniformOutput', false);

% concatenate the results
conc = cat(1, cellOfIntegrals{:});
```

Taking inspiration from user2305193's answer, here's an even better "loop-free" solution, based on reshaping the matrix and applying `trapz` along the appropriate dimension:

```
datReshaped = reshape(datimf, nrows, nmats, ncols);
solution = squeeze(trapz(datReshaped, 1));

% verify solutions are equivalent: 
all(solution(:) == conc(:))  % ans = true
```

Comment: Technically the use of `cellfun` is a loop.  Don't mean to discredit your answer, but you may want to rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want.  The third loop is unnecessary as both the inner and outer loops are 100 elements long.  Also the way you have it you are assigning `singleframe` lots more times than necessary since it does not depend on the inner loops `j` or `k`.  You were also trying to add `int_frame_all` to `conc`  before `int_frame_all` was finished being populated.

On top of that the `j` loop isn't required either since trapz can operate on the entire matrix at once anyway.

I think this is closer to what you intended:

```
datimf = rand(224*100,640);

singleframe = zeros(224,640); 
int_frame_all = zeros(1,640); 
conc = zeros(100,640); 

for i=1:100
   idx = (i-1)*224+1;
   singleframe(:,:) = datimf(idx:idx+223,:);     
%    for j = 1:640         
%          int_frame_all(:,j) = trapz(singleframe(:,j));
%    end
   % The loop is uncessary as trapz can operate on the entire matrix at once.    
   int_frame_all = trapz(singleframe,1);
   %I think this is what you really want... 
   conc(i,:) = int_frame_all; 
end
```

Comment: I used this routine and it works perfectly to my aim. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're processing frames in a video.

The most efficent approach in my experience would be to reshape `datimf` to be 3-dimensional. This can easily be achieved with the `reshape` command.

something along the line of `vid=reshape(datimf,224,640,[]);` should get you far in this regard, where the 3rd dimension is time. `vid(:,:,1)` then would display the first frame of the video.